# Selenium Integration in Jenkins from Ubuntu using Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, ubuntu, jenkins

I am able to execute my selenium scripts locally in Eclipse as Maven Project.

I am unable to execute the scripts in Jenkins from Ubuntu.

I have successfully configured jenkins and Build is successful. But scripts are not getting executed.

I am using local workspace.

Can someone please help me to find a solution?

My `pom.xml` as follows:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>ExpertusONE_4.5</groupId>
        <artifactId>ExpertusONE_4.5</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>ExpertusONE_4.5</name>
        <description>ExpertusONE_4.5</description>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.141.59</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>

            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                        <includes>
                            <include>CreateOrganization.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

        </build>


        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8.0_222</java.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>

    </project>
```

My console Output in Jenkins as follows:

```
Console Output
Started by user unknown or anonymous
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /home/nivedab/ExpertusONE_4.5
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 38039
[ExpertusONE_4.5] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.13.jar:/opt/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar:/opt/maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /opt/maven /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.33.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.13.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.13.jar 38039
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /home/nivedab/ExpertusONE_4.5/pom.xml process-test-classes
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< ExpertusONE_4.5:ExpertusONE_4.5 >-------------------
[INFO] Building ExpertusONE_4.5 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ExpertusONE_4.5 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 218 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ ExpertusONE_4.5 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ExpertusONE_4.5 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/nivedab/ExpertusONE_4.5/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ExpertusONE_4.5 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Join notifier requires a CauseAction
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.744 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-05T14:26:37+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/nivedab/ExpertusONE_4.5/pom.xml to ExpertusONE_4.5/ExpertusONE_4.5/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ExpertusONE_4.5-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Notifying upstream projects of job completion.
```

My Jenkins job configuration:

[jenkins job configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SihMt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is the plugins version.I am using two plugins **maven-surefire-plugin** & **maven-compiler-plugin** with mention version. When I am used other version it does not work for me. You can give a try

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>VRS_NEW</groupId>
<artifactId>Regression_New</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>vrsautomation</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```